# PHP Add string to line 2

Tags: php, file, csv, append

I want to add a string (the value of a DOM element - `$entry = stripslashes($_GET["nameofmytextarea"]);`) to the second line of `myfile.csv` (so as not to delete the header).

I don't care about CSV stuff, everything is already formatted. Just treat it as a text string being added to a text file.

I don't want anything complicated, just skip the first line and "append" above the second line: under the header but above all the other CSV lines.

How hard can that be?

Comment: It's nearly 2012, and you're _still_ running with `magic_quotes_gpc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$contents = explode("\n", file_get_contents('myfile.csv'), 2);
file_put_contents('myfile.csv', $contents[0]."\n".$entry."\n".$contents[1]);
```

This should work if the lines are separated by unix-lineendings.
If the file first looks like this:

```
header
content
content2
```

and the code is run with `$entry = 'test';` it will look like this afterwards:

```
header
test
content
content2
```

Comment: Yep, this works, I didn't know you could do that. Thanks for helping a n00b out man!

Comment: No Problem :) That's why we are here.

Comment: Just be sure to check that `$contents[1]` is set, or you will end up with a blank line at the end of the file, and an `E_NOTICE` - that's one reason why I prefer the `array_splice()` approach...

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) is what you need here:

```
function prepend_to_csv ($file, $line) {
  if (!$data = file($file)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  array_splice($data, 1, 0, $line.PHP_EOL);
  return (bool) file_put_contents($file, $data);
}

if (prepend_to_csv('myfile.csv', "this,is,some,data")) {
  echo 'Success';
} else {
  echo 'Fail';
}
```

Because of the way this method works, you need to ensure that you manually add the EOL to the new line yourself.